# why do I need to create a reference of A class, and then an object of B class

Tags: java, kotlin

I am new in programing and i am watching youtube tutorial (10:05-10:47)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssAt_qrQpi0&index=31&list=PLsyeobzWxl7rooJFZhc3qPLwVROovGCfh
and I do not understand why we could need reference of class A and an object of class B?

Kotlin example from that video:
var h: Human = Alien()

Java example from that video
Human h = new Alien()

reference of human and object of alien

Comment: That would be better if you describe your question instead of posting a 11-minuet-length youtube video. Google "inheritance in Java tutorial". In this case Java lets you instantiate Human with Alien class, because Alien **is a** Human.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of "Human" and "Alien" is terrible here. Instead of "Human", think "Animal". Instead of "Alien", think "Dog".

The terminology isn't great either. The "Object" is the literal object itself: the physical Dog <-> the bits associated with it in memory. The "Reference" is the variable, `h`. It references the object Dog. `h` is not a "reference of Animal and object of Dog", as the video says with Human/Alien. It's a "reference to a Dog object". However, the variable "h" itself, it not *forced* to reference *only* Dogs. In fact, it can reference any Animal.

For example, I can write the code:

```
Animal mypet = new Dog();
mypet = new Cat();
```

If I wrote the line `Dog mypet`, then I would be *forced* to only write `mypet = new Dog()` or `mypet = getDogFromShelter(myNeighborhoodShelter)`. It would not let me write `mypet = new Cat()`.

Cats are cool, so that would be terrible. Hence, we write `Animal mypet` to allow the variable `mypet` reference *any* animal. `Dog`, `Cat`, `Elephant` will all be available. However, because of this restriction, I am not allowed to do any `Dog`-specific things to `mypet`.

`mypet.bark()` will not work if `mypet` is an Animal. Not all Animals can bark. `mypet.eat(Food)` will work, since all Animals can eat. If I want my pet to Bark, because I know it is a Dog right now, then I can do

`((Dog)mypet)).bark();
// Will throw run-time error if mypet is not a Dog!
// This is best to avoid, so just make mypet a Dog type if it must bark.
// If you must make an Animal bark, use if (!(mypet instanceof Dog)) to handle the error propely.`

This above code will check to make sure `mypet` is a dog before letting it bark.

This can be implemented in code by writing

```
class Animal {
    int health = 100;
    void eat(Food f) {
        health += f.value;
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal { // States that "All Dogs are Animals"
    // The word "extends" allows you to write Animal a = new Dog();
    // "extends" also lets you do "Dog a = new Dog(); a.eat()"
    int health = 150; // Dogs are strong
    void bark() {
        scareNearbyAnimals();
    }
}

class Poodle extends Dog {
    // Both of these will work:
    // Dog mydog = new Poodle();
    // Animal mypet = new Poodle();
    int glamor = 50; // glamorous
}
```

The video mixed up Object vs Reference, so I'll make it more explicit with the following code

`Dog a = new Dog();
b = a;`

`a` and `b` both reference the same object in this instance. If `Dog` uses a lot of memory, then `b = a` does not cause more memory to be allocated.

`b.hasEaten(); // False
a.eat();
b.hasEaten(); // True
b = new Dog(); // Now they are different. a does not affect b`

`a.eat()` allowed the object to eat. The bits in memory have changed: the hunger value has been reset. `b.hasEaten()` checks the hunger value of the same Dog that `a` used when it was eating. `b = new Dog()` will separate them, so that `a` and `b` reference distinct dog objects. They will then no longer coupled as they were before.

Comment: Thank you! The best explanation!

Comment: @ПавелМалиновский Another important aspect is that of [virtual functions](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/virtual-function-in-java/). Even though a.bark() will not work, a.eat() will call Dog's version of eat, not Animal's version. If you understand my post, [abstract classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html), and virtual functions, then you've know everything there is to know about inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me explain you.

We want to create an object "man" of class Human assuming that "man" is a human.
We give the human class some functions that human can do. Let's say walk, run, sit.
Each function tells the object (man) what to do.

In the other hand, we want to create a class for Aliens to create another object. We'll name it "alien". Assume that alien is a humanoid so it can do whatever human can, plus some other special abilities that human cannot. For example "fly".

In order to prevent it to write the exact same functions (walk, run, sit) to class Alien. we inherit the class Human so we can get the functions (walk, run, sit) from Human class.

So let's say:
Human h -> the object "h" is a human(oid)

But "h" is actually an alien so we have to define it so there comes the code:

```
Human h = new Alien();
```

In other words. Imagine that you have a structure like this:

```
Human (functions: walk, run, sit)
 -- Alien (functions: (inherit: walk, run, sit), fly)
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I hope that helps.